# How do I change the border color of a Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker, watchos

I have a Picker in my View and I don't know how to access the border color. This is the code:

```
Picker("Select a Project", selection: $selectedProjectString){
            ForEach(projects, id: \.self) {
                Text($0).lineLimit(1).frame(height:120)
            }
        }.foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .frame(height: 120)
```

The Picker looks like this and I want the green border to be white too.

[image]

Thanks

Update:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a custom extension. You can set your border color to any color. (code is below the image)

Credit to @[Tamas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151675/tam%C3%A1s-sengel)

[image]

Tested view:

```
Picker("Select a Project", selection: $pick){
                ForEach(animal, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0).lineLimit(1).frame(height:120)
                }
    }
    .focusBorderColor(color: .red)
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .frame(height: 120)
```

Extension:

```
extension Picker {
func focusBorderColor(color: Color) -> some View {
    let isWatchOS7: Bool = {
        if #available(watchOS 7, *) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }()

    let padding: EdgeInsets = {
        if isWatchOS7 {
            return .init(top: 17, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
        }
        return .init(top: 8.5, leading: 0.5, bottom: 8.5, trailing: 0.5)
    }()

    return self
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: isWatchOS7 ? 8 : 7)
                .stroke(color, lineWidth: isWatchOS7 ? 4 : 3.5)
                .offset(y: isWatchOS7 ? 0 : 8)
                .padding(padding)
        )
  }
}
```

Comment: Small question that maybe sound dumb but I have never added an extension. Can I add this just to my normal code above the view struct or do I create a new empty swift file and add this code there?

Comment: Put it below your struct{} view in the same file, or create an independent file for it if you have tons of code. something like this -> struct ContentView{{}} extension{}. If you create an independent file, create a SwiftUI file.

Comment: I added your extension and removed my own customizations and now it looks like what I added to my question

Comment: You see the .overlay and padding part inside the extension right? That’s where you can customize your own size and corner radius for your watch. You just need to input the number that you need. It’s all about customization.